# How to separate a column list of fixed size X to X different columns?

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have a `tibble` with one column being a `list` column, *always* having two numeric values named `a` and `b` (e.g. as a result of calling `purrr:map` to a function which returns a *list*), say:

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(list(a = 1, b = 2), list(a = 3, b = 4), list(a = 5, b = 6)))
df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  x          y
 <int>     <list>
1     1 <list [2]>
2     2 <list [2]>
3     3 <list [2]>
```

How do I separate the list column `y` into two columns `a` and `b`, and get:

```
df_res <- tibble(x = 1:3, a = c(1,3,5), b = c(2,4,6))
df_res
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  x     a     b
 <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2
2     2     3     4
3     3     5     6
```

Looking for something like `tidyr::separate` to deal with a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr (current release: 0.7.0):

```
bind_cols(df[1], bind_rows(df$y))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#       x     a     b
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     2
# 2     2     3     4
# 3     3     5     6
```

#### edit based on OP's comment:

To embed this in a pipe and in case you have many non-list columns, we can try:

```
df %>% select(-y) %>% bind_cols(bind_rows(df$y))
```

Comment: Thank you. How to put this in a pipe? `df %>% select(x) %>% bind_cols(bind_rows(df$y))` or do you have something more elegant?

Comment: @GioraSimchoni I am not good at using `%>%`. I think your code is already simple enough.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni, slightly more flexible: `df %>% select(-y) %>% bind_cols(bind_rows(df$y))`

Answer (score 1):

We could also make use the `map_df` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  summarise(x = list(x), new = list(map_df(.$y, bind_rows))) %>%
  unnest
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     a     b
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     2
#2     2     3     4
#3     3     5     6
```